# SQL Server query cannot exclude row

Tags: sql-server

Can you help me to exclude record `Wszyscy` from column `Firma` in that query?

```
SELECT        
    Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis, Kto, ID
FROM
    Rok2016
WHERE        
    (Kto = @x) AND (Firma = @y)
```

I tried `EXCEPT Firma ='Wszyscy'`but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Well `... AND Firma = @y AND Firma != 'Wszyscy'`  -  But the only effect of this is to prevent any rows being found when @y is  'Wszyscy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or using a wild card

```
SELECT        Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis, Kto, ID
FROM            Rok2016
WHERE        (Kto = @x) AND (Firma = @y)
  AND Firma not like '%Wszyscy%';
```

More information using a wild card. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        Firma, Czas, Dzien, Opis, Kto, ID
FROM            Rok2016
WHERE        (Kto = @x) AND (Firma = @y)
  AND Firma <> 'Wszyscy'
```